Why can't I create partition in Milvus running on Docker Compose
I'm new to Milvus so I'm trying to get familiar with it (not Milvus Lite) and I'm running it on Docker Compose. I want to create a partition but I'm receiving an error. How can I fix this issue? Just to make clear, it's not Milvus Lite, it's normal Milvus so partitions should be supported.
My code
from pymilvus import MilvusClient, DataType
import json

client = MilvusClient(
    uri="localhost",
    token="root:Milvus"
)

# drop collection if exists
if client.has_collection(collection_name="dockerDB"):
    client.drop_collection(collection_name="dockerDB")

# need to create schema for customized setup
testSchema = MilvusClient.create_schema(
    enable_dynamic_field=True,
    partition_key_field="sku",
    num_partitions=16
)

testSchema.add_field(field_name="Auto_id", datatype=DataType.INT64, description="The Primary Key", is_primary=True,
                     auto_id=True)
testSchema.add_field(field_name="vector", datatype=DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR, metric_type="COSINE", dim=5)
testSchema.add_field(field_name="text", datatype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=8192)
testSchema.add_field(field_name="sku", datatype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=32)
testSchema.add_field(field_name="metadata", datatype=DataType.JSON)

# add index
indexParams = MilvusClient.prepare_index_params()
indexParams.add_index(
    field_name="vector",
    metric_type="COSINE",
    index_name="test-index"
)

# creating collection named 'dockerDB'
client.create_collection(
    collection_name="dockerDB",
    schema=testSchema,
    index_params=indexParams,
    auto_id=False
)
# View collections
collection = client.describe_collection(
    collection_name="dockerDB",
)

print("TEST COLLECTION DESCRIPTION:\n\n", collection)
print("\n\n\n")

client.create_partition(
    collection_name="dockerDB",
    partition_name="partitionA"
)

Error I'm receiving:
grpc RpcError: [create_partition], <_MultiThreadedRendezvous: StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED, >, <Time:{'RPC start': '2024-07-15 23:15:07.309182', 'gRPC error': '2024-07-15 23:15:07.311418'}>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/milvus-docker-test/milvus_docker_intro.py", line 59, in <module>
    client.create_partition(
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/milvus_client/milvus_client.py", line 776, in create_partition
    conn.create_partition(collection_name, partition_name, timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py", line 161, in handler
    raise e from e
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py", line 143, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py", line 182, in handler
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py", line 91, in handler
    raise e from e
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/decorators.py", line 87, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymilvus/client/grpc_handler.py", line 403, in create_partition
    response = rf.result()
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 883, in result
    raise self
grpc._channel._MultiThreadedRendezvous: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED
        details = ""
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer  {created_time:"2024-07-15T23:15:07.310883188+00:00", grpc_status:12, grpc_message:""}"


